# COUNT DISTINCT + WINDOW FUNCTION with conditions SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle-sqldeveloper, distinct

I have a data table as below:

| CustomerID | Contract_id | Value_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1234 | 01-JUL-20 |
| A | 7896 | 20-DEC-20 |
| C | 6578 | 01-JUN-20 |
| C | 8990 | 20-OCT-20 |
| C | 4789 | 20-DEC-21 |
| B | 3457 | 09-SEP-21 |

I tried to count distinct number of `Contract_id` before each `Value_date` for each unique `CustomerID`.

The desired result is:

| CustomerID | Value_date | Count_contract |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01-JUL-20 | 0 |
| A | 20-DEC-20 | 1 |
| C | 01-JUN-20 | 0 |
| C | 20-OCT-20 | 1 |
| C | 20-DEC-21 | 2 |
| B | 09-SEP-21 | 0 |

```
Could anyone suggest how I could count distinct in this case?

I tried the window functions:

select distinct CustomerID,
Value_date,
count(distinct Contract_id) over (partition by CustomerID order by Value_date rows unbounded preceding) count_contract
from tbl_cus_contract;
```

but it didn't work with the error:

> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here 30487. 00000 -  "ORDER BY not allowed here"
> *Cause:    DISTINCT functions and RATIO_TO_REPORT cannot have an ORDER BY
> *Action:

THANK YOU ALL FELLOWS FOR THE ANSWERS!!!
I found a nicer way to count distinct as several different Contract_id of the same CustomerID have same value_date.

I was using `rank()`

Here is my solution:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c145c0432e003c1be52dbe0685c8d259

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I forgot the expected outcome. Very sorry! I just edited it in the question! Thanks

Comment: what happens if a contract_id is repeated over more than 1 date for the same customer? (can this happen?)

Comment: @PaulMaxwell My tbl_cus_contract has unique contract_id, the case could happen is some different contracts of one customer could have the same date. Thank you for your idea!

Comment: @1darknight Sample data in your db fiddle link is having same contract_id for 2 different dates (i.e. for 'C') but you are saying you have unique contract_ids.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the first occurrence of the `contract_id` for a given customer.
Then Count only the first occurrence.

```sql
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT customerid,value_date,contract_id,
                CASE WHEN Row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY customerid, contract_id
                           ORDER BY value_date ) = 1 THEN 1
                END AS first_occurrence_of_contract
         FROM   tbl_cus_contract
)
SELECT customerid,value_date,
       Count(first_occurrence_of_contract)
         OVER (PARTITION BY customerid 
              ORDER BY value_date ROWS unbounded preceding) - 1 AS count_contract
FROM   cte
```

db<>fiddle: [Try here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c58ad6eeea8137e6e69fa16659a3228f)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a nicer way to use in my Oracle 19c using rank(). Here is my solution:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c145c0432e003c1be52dbe0685c8d259

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result does not appear to require counting distinct contract_id's and if that is true then you could just omit the use of distinct within the count and your query would work.

```
SELECT t1.CustomerID
    , t1.Value_date
    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.CustomerID ORDER BY t1.Value_date) - 1
FROM tbl_cus_contract t1
ORDER BY t1.CustomerID
    , t1.Value_date
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a nicer way to use in my Oracle 19c using rank(). Here is my solution:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c145c0432e003c1be52dbe0685c8d259

Answer (score 0):

This may be done with a `model` clause:

> ```
> select *
> from t
> model
>   /*The same as in analytic function*/
>   partition by (customer_id)
>   /*This would be used as ordering criteria later*/
>   dimension by (dt)
>   measures (
>     /*Need to specify all the columns
>       not in partition or dimension*/
>     contract_id,
>     0 as cnt
>   )
>   rules (
>     cnt[any] =
>       /*dt <= cv(dt) is all dates before
>       the current value of date.
>       The same as window specification*/
>       count(distinct contract_id)[dt <= cv(dt)]
>   )
> ```
>
> ```
> CUSTOMER_ID | DT        | CONTRACT_ID | CNT
> :---------- | :-------- | ----------: | --:
> A           | 01-JUL-20 |        1234 |   1
> A           | 20-DEC-20 |        7896 |   2
> C           | 01-JUN-20 |        6578 |   1
> C           | 20-OCT-20 |        8990 |   2
> C           | 20-DEC-21 |        4789 |   3
> C           | 23-DEC-21 |        4789 |   3
> B           | 09-SEP-21 |        3457 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=80685485145a022389f2ef424924f0d3)*

**UPD**: In case of multiple `contract_id` per date you may add `unique single reference`, so `model` will not comply on duplicated dimension values. See updated code and a result:

> ```
> select *
> from t
> model
>   /*The same as in analytic function*/
>   partition by (customer_id)
>   /*This would be used as ordering criteria later*/
>   dimension by (dt)
>   measures (
>     /*Need to specify all the columns
>       not in partition or dimension*/
>     contract_id,
>     0 as cnt
>   )
>   unique single reference
>   rules (
>     cnt[any] =
>       /*dt <= cv(dt) is all dates before
>       the current value of date.
>       The same as window specification*/
>       count(distinct contract_id)[dt <= cv(dt)]
>   )
> ```
>
> ```
> CUSTOMER_ID | DT        | CONTRACT_ID | CNT
> :---------- | :-------- | ----------: | --:
> A           | 01-JUL-20 |        1234 |   1
> A           | 20-DEC-20 |        7896 |   2
> C           | 01-JUN-20 |        6578 |   1
> C           | 20-OCT-20 |        8990 |   3
> C           | 20-OCT-20 |        9999 |   3
> C           | 20-DEC-21 |        4789 |   4
> C           | 23-DEC-21 |        4789 |   4
> B           | 09-SEP-21 |        3457 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a5b9e9dd642177696f6771a8cb36947e)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found a nicer solution using rank() as there was also some different contract_Id of a customerID has the same date. 
Also, many thanks for the db<> fiddle. My solution are::https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c145c0432e003c1be52dbe0685c8d259

Comment: @1darknight But this does very different calculation. I've updated my answer to count such a case also